# VB.Net grade distribution exercise

Tags: vb.net

So I really need help in doing this exercise. The user has to input a grade, and after typing the grade in txtGrade, it will be distributed in four textboxes.

For example, the user inputs 50 in txtGrade.

**The output should be:**

CS: 20 
IT: 10 
EX: 10 
EM: 10

The order is not necessary.

So this is what I have tried:

```
 Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    txtA.Text = txtGrade.Text
End Sub
```

But I can't seem to think of how to distribute it to other textboxes.

Comment: Logic for distribution..?

Comment: Yes because I don't know if I'm about to use array in here

Comment: What ration consider to cs,it.. For eg cs=20% , It =30% like..

Comment: No but there are four subjects so I have to distribute it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
If txtGrade.Text <> "" Then
    If CDbl(txtGrade.Text) Then
    texCS.Text = (CDbl(txtGrade.Text) * 40 ) / 100
    texIT.Text = (CDbl(txtGrade.Text) * 20 ) / 100
    texEX.Text = (CDbl(txtGrade.Text) * 20 ) / 100
    texEMP.Text = (CDbl(txtGrade.Text) * 20 ) / 100
    End If

End If
```

Comment: this seems nice, but can I just produce without 12.5?

Comment: I can't understand..? without 12.5 means..?

Comment: Because I tried to input 50, it gives 12.5 in each textboxes. What I mean it should not fairly distribute. Just like my example.

Comment: Okay but this time it gives 125, 250, 250, 250 outputs

Comment: thanks! Now can you give me ways to randomize their position upon button click? Tell me if I need to create another thread. ty

Comment: Hai Dunkey.. Your native..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34163/discussion-between-dunkey-and-selvam)