# VB.net random position of numbers in textboxes

Tags: vb.net, textbox

So this is just a continuation of my question [VB.Net grade distribution exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858464/vb-net-grade-distribution-exercise/17858699#17858699)

But what I wanna do now is swap or randomize their positions upon button click.

So this is what I'm working on:

```
    If txtGrade.Text <> "" Then
        If CDbl(txtGrade.Text) Then
            txtA.Text = (CDbl(txtGrade.Text) * 40) / 100
            txtB.Text = (CDbl(txtGrade.Text) * 20) / 100
            txtC.Text = (CDbl(txtGrade.Text) * 30) / 100
            txtD.Text = (CDbl(txtGrade.Text) * 10) / 100
        End If
    End If
```

**UPDATE:**
I put this above code upon txtGrade_TextChanged event

But I really don't have an idea how to randomize their position. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon clicking your button, you need to store the values you want to swap/randomize/shuffle into a `List(Of T)`, like this:

```
Dim ValuesToShuffle = New List(Of String)
ValuesToShuffle.Add(txtA.Text)
ValuesToShuffle.Add(txtB.Text)
ValuesToShuffle.Add(txtC.Text)
ValuesToShuffle.Add(txtD.Text)
```

Now you are going to loop through the values to shuffle and generate a random number each time and move value around, like this:

```
Dim rand = New Random()

For counter = 0 to ValuesToShuffle.Count- 1
    Dim n = rand.Next(counter + 1)
    Dim temp = ValuesToShuffle(counter)
    ValuesToShuffle(counter) = ValuesToShuffle(n)
    ValuesToShuffle(n) = temp
Next
```

Finally, put the shuffled values back into the textboxes, like this:

```
txtA.Text = ValuesToShuffle(0)
txtB.Text = ValuesToShuffle(1)
txtC.Text = ValuesToShuffle(2)
txtD.Text = ValuesToShuffle(3)
```

Comment: Thanks where do I put the List(Of T) ?

Comment: In the click handler for your button or in a separate method that gets called by your click handler. I would get it working how you want and then refactor into separate methods and potentially a utility method that could be used by other code/pages in your application.

Comment: Okay but I got a problem in here saying: 'Length' is not a member of System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: Ah sorry I typed to quickly and had a brain fart, that should be `Count` not `Length`. Updated answer.

Comment: @Dunkey - great, good luck with your grade distribution exercise. Feel free to accept this answer if you feel it helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Random` class: (edited to show a more concise version)

```
Dim grade As Double
If Double.TryParse(txtGrade.Text, grade) Then
    Dim values = {(grade * 40 / 100).ToString(), (grade * 20 / 100).ToString(), (grade * 30 / 100).ToString(), (grade * 10 / 100).ToString()}
    FillRandomControlText({txtA, txtB, txtC, txtD}, values)
End If
```

with this method:

```
Shared Sub FillRandomControlText(txtControls As IList(Of TextBox), values As IList(Of String))
    Dim rnd = New Random()
    Dim txt As TextBox
    Dim selectedControls = New List(Of Control)(txtControls.Count)
    For i As Int32 = 0 To txtControls.Count - 1
        Do
            txt = txtControls(rnd.Next(txtControls.Count))
        Loop While selectedControls.Contains(txt)
        selectedControls.Add(txt)
        txt.Text = values(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

<strike>Dim grade As Double
    Dim rnd = New Random()
    Dim controls = {txtA, txtB, txtC, txtD}
    Dim selectedControls = New List(Of Control)
    Dim txt As TextBox</strike>

```
If Double.TryParse(txtGrade.Text, grade) Then
    Do
        txt = controls(rnd.Next(controls.Length))
    Loop While selectedControls.Contains(txt)
    selectedControls.Add(txt)
    txt.Text = (grade * 40 / 100).ToString()
    Do
        txt = controls(rnd.Next(controls.Length))
    Loop While selectedControls.Contains(txt)
    selectedControls.Add(txt)
    txt.Text = (grade * 20 / 100).ToString()
    Do
        txt = controls(rnd.Next(controls.Length))
    Loop While selectedControls.Contains(txt)
    selectedControls.Add(txt)
    txt.Text = (grade * 30 / 100).ToString()
    Do
        txt = controls(rnd.Next(controls.Length))
    Loop While selectedControls.Contains(txt)
    txt.Text = (grade * 10 / 100).ToString()
End If
```

Comment: Ouch... that does not look very DRY.

Comment: @Neolisk: Not really, however, since i don't know the logic behind those different factors i have left it as it was. That cries out for a method ;)

Comment: @Neolisk: Better? ;-)

Comment: Yep, something like that. +1 for your efforts.